# SETTINGS Drive Accidentally Renamed!

Tags: pi-3, noobs, failure, settings

Here is a link to what i mean by SETTINGS Drive: [Settings partition on eject menu](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44079/settings-partition-on-eject-menu)

I was doing some stuff, and when i rebooted, i got a message in NOOBS saying something like the SETTINGS Drive could not be found. And it went to the NOOBS setup. I just clicked Exit. And now its called "34 MB Volume"

So how do i rename it back to "SETTINGS"?? Also the folder its mounted to is a bunch of numbers and letters.

PLEASE HELP!

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
When asking about this, I accidentally ejected the drive. So i finished it quickly then rebooted. When rebooting, i didn't get the error, but the SETTINGS Drive is still named the same. The folder is called "b63d00b7-347f-4177-a5ed-e89235de2e77".

Answer (score 1):

The "drive" you were looking at is a partition on your SD Card.

This is `/dev/mmcblk0p5` and contains the `NOOBS` boot files.

This is automatically mounted by the GUI in `/media/pi/SETTINGS/`

`sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0p5` will show you the properties of the partition.

If you (or the system) renamed it this will show the name, but it should not affect the system operation.

The "bunch of numbers and letters" would be the `UUID` of the partition.

`sudo e2label /dev/mmcblk0p5 SETTINGS` should set the name, although you may have to unmount first.